# In Django using ORM., how to do multiple self join on different values

Tags: python, mysql, django, orm

Could any one help me to how to write multiple self join on different values in Django using ORM ?

For example., We have two tables. (1) projects (2) project_tab_status

[image: tables as picture]

I have wrote the query as below and not able to access the second join fields:

```
Project.objects.filter(projecttabstatus__tab_status_type='processor1').annotate(tab_status_type_bv=Concat('projecttabstatus__tab_status_type', Value(''), Value('')),tab_status_bv=Concat('projecttabstatus__tab_status', Value(''), Value(''))).filter(projecttabstatus__tab_status_type='processor2').values('name', 'tab_status_type_bv', 'projecttabstatus__tab_status_type', 'projecttabstatus__tab_status', 'tab_status_bv', 'projecttabstatus__id').filter(id=698)
```

but the second processor's values are not coming properly.

Comment: post the model structure

Comment: Hi Mr Exprator, thanks for choosing my question.. please click below link to get model structure https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOiFO.png

Answer (score 0):

you can try following the relationship [backward](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward).

```
all_projects = Projects.objects.all()
for project in all_projects:
    project.project_tab_status_set.all()  # this will give you the project_tab_status objects associated with a given project.
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for choosing my question. actually the same for loop we are looping through the parent projects. and parent projects dont mapped with project_tab_status. only child projects are mapped with project_tab_status table. (thats why i kept parent_project_id filter in the above query.)

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean by parent project and child project ?